# Angular 2+ navigation with mat-tab-nav-bar - accessibility

Tags: angular, accessibility, router-outlet

Angular material gives us in-app [navigation with tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation).

By Angular:

> `<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>` provides a **tab-like UI** for navigating between routes.

I want to make it more accessibile.

What we have now:

1. Navigation with arrows (<kbd>left</kbd><kbd>right</kbd><kbd>up</kbd><kbd>down</kbd>) throw the list items.
2. <kbd>Enter</kbd> activate the selected tab.
3. <kbd>Tab</kbd> focus on the elements in DOM as usual (not update the selection as the arrow keys, details below).

Accessibility requirements:

1. <kbd>Tab</kbd> will focus on the active tab (not necessary the focused tab).
2. <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> on the nav list will jump to previous element in the DOM, befor the `nav` item.
   On the content page of the router <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> will jump from the first focusable element to the previous active element in the `nav`.
3. <kbd>Space</kbd> should activate the selected tab like mouse click and <kbd>Enter</kbd> press.
4. The elements in the `nav` (`a` elements) will be with the right `aria` roles.

I don't want to change the structure, just add it the accessibility that expected from tabs.

Any help please?
How can I achieve the focus on the content from the `nav` in the correct way with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> keys?

Looking for correct structure.

---

#### More Details:

The `mat-tab-nav-bar` and `mat-tab-link` directive of angular for navigation are provide only a 'like' tabs UI.
I want to enable in-app routing navigation by `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` directive element with keyboard accessibility.

From accessibility aspect I would expect navigate through the links with `arrow keys`, `Enter` activate the selected tab and `Tab` key will move the focus to the content of the routed page.

Because I want to update the URL when the user chage tabs I used the `nav` element with [angular](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation) `mat-tab-nav-bar` directive, like in the example below:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
  *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles; let i = index" 
    routerLink="{{vehicle}}"
            routerLinkActive="active"
    (click)="activeLink = vehicle"
    [active]="activeLink == vehicle">
    {{vehicle}}
  </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In a 'real' `nav` and `a` element you can navigate with keyboard only by `Tab`, but not with arrow keys.
But with the `mat-tab-nav-bar` directive the routing throw the tabs work indeed by arrows, but the `Tab` is not disabled for the `a` element.

I want to enable the `tab` key move to the content of the selected tab.
I thought about angular FocusMonitor, or KeyManager to solve this situation, but couldn't achieve the desired result.
I can also auto capture the focus to the selected tab content, but again it's not exactly the behavior of tabs.

For example, in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rul4hb) I want to navigate the tabs "Cars", "Airplanes" and "Bikes" with the arrow keys. When tab selected (with `Enter` or `mouse`) the `Tab` key will navigate to the input filed in the content.
Currently what I achieved is just focus on the input when one tab selected (as shown in the "Bikes" tab). But I want to navigate like real tabs.

BTW,
If you navigate throw the tabs with `Tab` on the `mat-tab-nav-bar` directive you will see the focus move from tab to tab, and press on enter will fire the click event on the `a` element. But if you press on the arrow keys to navigate throw the tabs, the focus will jump to the last active tab.
simple reproduce: navigate with `Tab` key twice and press on the `right-arrow` key. you'll see the focus 'jumped' one step backward.

Here you can see the difference (examples from the official [site](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples)):

['Real' tabs](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nvpmmxdoxqly?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.ts): press on tab will enter to the content of the tab.

['Like' tabs](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lvxvqqkopkg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-nav-bar-basic-example.ts): press on tab will just move on throw the elements in the DOM.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I am not following what your desired behaviour is, do you want behaviour like the 'Real' tabs or like the 'Working example'. I Reread question a few times but still not following. I think you are trying to dynamically load a page from a menu bar and then make sure that the next time you press 'tab' it goes into the new page content. If so are you open to a slightly 'better' (more widely accepted) way of doing this that would allow you to have a standard navigation element in your App / Website and accounts for some issues with dynamic loading? Did I understand or is it something else?

Comment: Thanks @GrahamRitchie. I want it to work like real tabs (arrows move throw the tabs and `Tab` navigate to selected tab content). I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great solution for the main question - the <kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>shift+Tab</kbd> issue.

[Simple directive](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rul4hb-6ze5zl) do the work.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[mat-tab-link]',
  host: {
      '[attr.tabindex]': 'getTabIndex',
  }
})
export class AccessibleTabNavDirective {

  constructor(private tabLink: MatTabLink) { }

  get getTabIndex() {
    return this.tabLink.active ? 0 : -1;
  }
}
```

Please note that in one case it's lackey. If one tab selected and previous tab focused the next tab will focus on the selected tab. For example: select the second tab and return to the previous tab (with <kbd>Left-arrow</kbd>) - the next <kbd>Tab</kbd> press will focus on the active tab and not on the page content.

But this issue happens in the 'real' angular tabs so I left it as is for now.

If you have a pretty solution for the <kbd>Space</kbd> too... you are welcome to comment.